# Query against sys.sql_expression_dependencies works in SSMS/Visual Studio but fails on SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a query which returns all our views and the tables/views they depend on. This query works fine in SSMS. I added it to my report, and it works fine in the preview. After I deploy, I get no results when I run from SSRS in browser.

```
SELECT 
  SCHEMA_NAME(v.schema_id) AS SchemaName, 
  v.name AS ViewName,
  SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id) AS RefSchemaName,
  o.name AS RefObjectName,
  o.type_desc AS RefObjectType
FROM sys.views v
JOIN sys.sql_expression_dependencies sed ON v.object_id = sed.referencing_id
JOIN sys.objects o ON sed.referenced_id = o.object_id
ORDER BY SchemaName, ViewName, RefSchemaName, RefObjectName, RefObjectType;
```

I eventually deduced that the reason I get no results is because of the `inner join` to `sys.sql_expression_dependencies`, which for some reason is not returning any rows in SSRS. I tried using `SELECT 1 FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies` , and the report showed no rows. So when deployed, seems like SSRS is not finding anything in that view.

I tried all the typical troubleshooting steps for SSRS results <> SSMS results that I have seen in other questions.

- I cleared the *.data files to make sure I'm looking at live data.
- I verified that I was using the correct data source.
- I made sure there wasn't any 'stuck' parameters in SSRS that were overriding the behaviors.
- I deleted the report from SSRS and re-deployed.
- I made a new report with a different name and same query and deployed.
- I quadruple checked that the query is the exact same as the one in SSMS.
- I checked the data source (again).

Running the query returns 1800+ rows in SSMS and Visual Studio Preview. Why would this view/join fail to return data once deployed?

Comment: Sounds like SSRS is connected to the wrong database (or is returning zero rows because of different permissions). Is SSRS connecting as a different user?

Comment: I would guess that the credentials being used do not have permissions. Check the datasource credentials on the server - they are not overwritten by default when deploying. Also try creating a new temporary test datasource that uses fixed sql credentials with known access (like 'sa') then point the report to that datasource.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: The issue here was that when running this report using the ReportReader account, this line:

`WHERE   HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME(QUOTENAME(DB_NAME()), 'DATABASE', 'VIEW DEFINITION') = 1;`

in `sql_expression_dependencies` was returning 0. Switched to a data source that executes as the end user instead of as ReportReader, and now it works. Thanks to Alan and Aaron for pointing me in the right direction.